# How do I password protect a page using UWP Windows Authetication

Tags: authentication, uwp

I am developing a UWP application which has a settings page for configuring account information need to run the application. Since the page has sensitive information and the app is a public Kiosk, I need prevent non-administrator principals from accessing the page.

What API(s) are available for UWP to authenticate a user as an administrator? I do not need to store the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the [guidance for creating a kiosk app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/partnerapps/create-a-kiosk-app-for-assigned-access)?

> If the kiosk app is meant to run both above lock in assigned access and also in the unlocked Windows context, you may want to create a different page to render above lock, and another page for under the lock. This will allow you to avoid showing sensitive information in kiosk mode, since kiosk mode usually means anonymous access. Here are the steps you'd follow to use two different pages, one for under the lock and one for above the lock:
>
> 1. Inside the override of the OnLaunched function in App.xaml.cs, try to obtain an instance of the LockApplicationHost class before rootFrame navigation.
> 2. If the call fails, the kiosk app should launch normally, under the lock.
> 3. If the call succeeds, the kiosk app should launch above the lock running in assigned access mode. You may want this version of the kiosk app to have a different main page to hide sensitive information.

There are further details and sample code if you follow the link as well as other tips and best practices for kiosk apps.